# Return n-th term of a mathematical sequence

Tags: python-3.x, math, sequence

I want  to create a def that you provide a positive integer `n` and a number `x`, and it returns the n-th term of the following sequence:

`x - x^3/3 + x^5/5 - x^7/7 + x^9/9 - x^11/11.....`
where:

first term  is:  `a1 = x`

second term is : `a2 = x - x^3/3`

third term  is:  `a3 = x - x^3/3 +x^5/5`
etc

This is what i came up with, but it doesn't seem to return constistent results compared to calculating the values manually. Please, tell me if I'm missing something! Thank you very much!

```
def madh(n, x):
    if n == 1:
        return x
    else:
        result = (((-1)**n) * (x ** (2*n-1)) / (2*n - 1)) + madh((n - 1), x)
        return result
```

Comment: You need the nth term, or sum up to nth term?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur The n-th term! I found it's the following! 
a(n) = a(n-1) + ((-1)^(n-1))*(x^(2*n-1)/2*n-1)  Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in the sign of the element. For example, the second term is negative, but it is positive in your case (`(-1) ** 2 = 1`). So, the corrected version is:

```py
def madh(n, x):
    if n == 1:
        return x
    else:
        # change n to (n+1) in the power of -1
        result = (((-1)**(n+1)) * (x ** (2 * n - 1)) / (2 * n - 1)) + madh((n - 1), x)
        return result
```

By the way, your function returns the sum of series up to `n`-th terms, not the `n`-th term of the series.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @peter !( Btw sorry for not being completely clear but it's the first time I'm asking a question here!). The sequence i want goes like this:

a1  =  x

a2  =  x - x^3/3 or a2 = a1 - x^3/3

a3 = x - x^3/3 + x^5/5 or a3 = a2 + x^5/5

a4 = x - x^3/3 + x^5/5 - x^7/7 or a4 = a3 - x^7/7

So a(n) = a(n-1) + ((-1)^(n-1))*(x^(2*n-1)/2*n-1)

I think I got it

`def madh(n, x):
    if n == 1:
        return x
    else:
        result = madh(n-1, x) + ((-1)**(n-1)) * (x**(2*n-1))/(2*n-1)
        return result
`

BY THE WAY WHY IS MY RESPONSE IN THIS FORMAT XD

Answer (score 0):

The `nth` term of the series is `((x^n)/n)*(-1^(n+1))`. Simple function for that would be

```py
def nth_num(n,x):
    if n==1:
        return x
    return nth_num(n-1,x) + ((x**n)/n)*(-1**(n+1))
```